# Set initial value in Combobox bound to CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, collectionviewsource

I am using WPF and an MVVM pattern. All the comboboxes that are bound to lists work fine, but I have a cascading dropdown that uses a `CollectionViewSource` for filtering. The filtering works, as does the setter (which while searching for an answer, I saw another person having trouble with), but I am unable to set the initial value. I have tried a few methods, but none seem to affect the selecteditem.

Viewmodel ctor, and Property setter (_ticket.SelectedSubstatus is set in the model constructor):

```
public TicketViewModel()
    {
        _ticket = new TicketModel();
        SubstatusList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GetStatusList());
        SubstatusList.Filter = (x) => { return (int)(x as Substatus).IST_MAIN_STATUS == (int)SelectedStatus.IST_STATUS_ID; };

        SubstatusList.MoveCurrentTo(_ticket.SelectedSubstatus);
        SelectedSubstatus = _ticket.SelectedSubstatus;

        Substatus test = (Substatus)SubstatusList.CurrentItem;

    }

public Substatus SelectedSubstatus
    {
        get { return _ticket.SelectedSubstatus; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _ticket.SelectedSubstatus ||value == null)
                return;

            _ticket.SelectedSubstatus = value;
            _ticket.Issue.IS_SUBSTATUS_ID = value.IST_SUBSTATUS_ID;

            base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSubstatus");
        }
    }
```

and here is the combobox XAML

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                  Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" 
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubstatusList}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSubstatus, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="IST_NAME"/>
```

The current item from the `CollectionViewSource` is null just after being set by MoveCurrentTo(), and when checked by test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, objects are checked if they are equal by reference, not value.

So if `_ticket.SelectedSubstatus` does not directly reference an item in `SubstatusList`, then the `SelectedSubstatus` will be NULL because you are trying to set the `SelectedSubstatus` equal to an item that doesn't exist in the `SubstatusList`

To get around this, overwrite the `.Equals()` method of `Substatus` to return true if an object's data is the same. For example,

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
      if (obj == null) return false;
      if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;

      return this.Id == ((SubStatus)obj).Id;
 }
```

Comment: You've got it backwards. The `SelectedSubstatus`is not null, and making a selection on the dropdown properly updates the `SelectedSubstatus`. Though I think this makes sense, if `SubstatusList.MoveCurrentTo(_ticket.SelectedSubstatus);` can't find the object in `SubstatusList`, it won't set it. How can I set the CurrentItem in SubstatusList?

Comment: Also, Substatus is an EF4 object. I tried placing that override in a partial class, but `ID` is not a valid property. I didn't see anything in Intellisense that would have worked.

Comment: Overwrite the `Equals()` in your `SubStatus` class to return true if the data is the same. Right now, its only returning true if the reference in memory is the same. The Id property was an example.

Comment: I tried using a property of the `Substatus` object, the PK from the EF object, and I get compile errors saying it doesn't contain a definition for that. I can access that property elsewhere in the code, but even on the casted object it won't let me.

Comment: Nvm, I apparently had two classes `Substatus` and `SubStatus`, and was making a partial on the wrong one. Not sure why I have two of them.